# Use LocalAddress in Puppeteer to rotate IP adressess for requests

Tags: javascript, proxy, request, puppeteer

I do have a VPS with multiple IPv4 addresses. I want to rotate them for sending multiple requests to a ratelimited website for webscraping purposes (basically as faster alternative to proxies, cause there is no additional delay like this).

When using the npm request lib I can easily do this with

```
request({
    url: "http://www.scrapethissitewithoutratelimit.com",
    method: "GET",
    localAddress: currentIP,
    gzip: true,
    headers: {
```

When using puppeteer I can also easily use a proxy to achieve the same via

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [ '--proxy-server=http://' + proxyList[proxyCounter] + ':80', ]
});
```

Now I want to do the same, but with localAddress instead of a proxy. Is it possible and if yes, what is the right syntax? I googled for quite a while but just can't find a good solution how to do this :-(

Thanks in advance fellows!

Comment: As in you have a proxy running on localhost:80 ? Then just put that.

Comment: I have no proxy running at all, these ips are bound to my server via network interface. And I wanna use them for outgoing requests.